# CustomTkinter's CTkScrollableFrame autoscroll to bottom (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a chat application using Tkinter + CustomTkinter . Basically my app, on clicking a button, places(packs) a label in the frame I have declared below, but as I go on clicking, the labels pile up, I have to manually scroll down to view the latest element .

```py
import customtkinter
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()

root.title("PizzaBot")
root.geometry("400x400")
root.resizable(False,False)
root.configure(background="#2C2C2C")

frameChat = customtkinter.CTkScrollableFrame(root, width=350,height=350)
frameChat.pack()

t=0
for i in range(20):
    t += 1000
    root.after(t, lambda: customtkinter.CTkLabel(frameChat, text="Hi").pack())
#code to scroll to bottom

#Whenever the text overflows the dimensions of "frameChat", it automatically must scroll down to the bottom so as to display the latest value
#The above code is just given as an example to show my problem
root.mainloop()
```

1: Text slowly starts going down
2: When it overflows the height of the frame, it gets wrapped but I am unable to figure out how to automatically scroll down the frame without me having to do it myself every time, an example is the image below

PS. I do not want to delete the elements at the top so as to make space for newer elements

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeR1l.png 
this is the image of the app

Comment: You can call `root.after(1, frameChat._parent_canvas.yview_moveto, 1)` after adding the label.

Comment: ```frameChat._parent_canvas.yview_moveto, 1``` does seem to be function, however the value of 1 doesn't seem to work

Comment: The valid value for `.yview_moveto()` is between 0 and 1.  0 means beginning and 1 means the end.  It works for me.

Comment: I tried it in my main code, it works, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can call root.after(1, frameChat._parent_canvas.yview_moveto, 1) after adding the label.

Answered by - acw1668

Answer (score 0):

this is answer for this

```
import customtkinter
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()

root.title("PizzaBot")
root.geometry("400x400")
root.resizable(False,False)
root.configure(background="#2C2C2C")

frameChat = customtkinter.CTkScrollableFrame(root, width=350,height=350)
frameChat.pack()

t=0
for i in range(20):
    t += 200
    root.after(t, frameChat._parent_canvas.yview_moveto, i)
    root.after(t, lambda: customtkinter.CTkLabel(frameChat, text="Hi").pack())
    
#code to scroll to bottom

#Whenever the text overflows the dimensions of "frameChat", it automatically must scroll down to the bottom so as to display the latest value
#The above code is just given as an example to show my problem
root.mainloop()
```